# Upgrade libc to version 2.9

Tags: ubuntu, glibc, libc

On Lubuntu 17.04 I have installed libc6 version 2.24, I need to upgrade it to version 2.9.

Any tips? Is it possible upgrade libc6 to this version?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can look for answer in https://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have installed libc6 version 2.24, I need to upgrade it to version 2.9.

You are *confused*: glibc-2.9 is extremely old and predates glibc-2.24 by many years.

If you did manage to *downgrade* your glibc to 2.9, all programs on your system would stop working, rendering your system unbootable.